# How do I conditionally add parameters to a SQLCommand object in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any different and better way to do this (This is just part of it):

```
if (dataRow["Row1"].ToString().Trim(' ') == string.Empty) 
        commandGI.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
else commandGI.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataRow["Row1"];
if (dataRow["Row2"].ToString().Trim(' ') == string.Empty) 
        commandGI.Parameters.Add("@IdentityInfo", SqlDbType.Text).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
else commandGI.Parameters.Add("@IdentityInfo", SqlDbType.Text).Value = dataRow["Row2"];
if (dataRow["Ro3"].ToString().Trim(' ') == string.Empty) 
        commandGI.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.Text).Value = System.DBNull.Value;
else commandGI.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.Text).Value = dataRow["Row3"];
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not generally bad to use multiple lines ;)

Comment: When you have a question for us, your title should be the actual problem that someone would search for if they had your issue.  No one will search for "Is there an easier way to write the following code."  Also, what issue are you seeing with this code? If you don't have an actual problem, you may want to try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher, then instead of `Trim` and then comparing it with `string.Empty` you can use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

```
if(dataRow["Rows"] != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataRow["Rows"].ToString())
```

Also check for `null` first to avoid Null reference exception.

If your `dataRow` corresponds to a row returned from a `DataReader` then you should check it against `DBNull.Value`

Comment: shouldn't it be `dataRow["Rows"] != DBNull.Value` ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, not really sure if it is coming from a database or a `DataTable` in memory.

Comment: looks like the OP is adding rows in database from a table in memory.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, added that as well, looks plausible.